# not getting the exact value for multiselect bottomsheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have made a multiselectbottomsheet field to select options but when I select and print the value it shows 'instance of Religion' instead of the value selected.
i have tried other options too but for me, nothing works.

below is the code for the same -:

```
  //===========================================================================to set value for Religion in chip

  static List<Religions> _religion = [
    Religions(id: 1, name: "Agnostic"),
    Religions(id: 2, name: "Atheist"),
    Religions(id: 3, name: "Buddhist"),
    Religions(id: 4, name: "Christian"),
    Religions(id: 5, name: "Hindu"),
    Religions(id: 6, name: "Jain"),
    Religions(id: 7, name: "Jewish"),
    Religions(id: 8, name: "Muslim"),
    Religions(id: 9, name: "Zoroastrian"),
    Religions(id: 10, name: "Sikh"),
    Religions(id: 11, name: "Spiritual"),
    Religions(id: 12, name: "Other"),
  ];
  final _items = _religion
      .map((item) => MultiSelectItem<Religions>(item, item.name))
      .toList();
  List<Religions> _selectedItems2 = [];
  List<Religions> _selectedItems3 = [];
  final _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();





                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    'What\'s their religion?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                        initialChildSize: 0.7,
                        maxChildSize: 0.95,
                        listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
                        checkColor: Colors.pink,
                        selectedColor: Colors.pink,
                        selectedItemsTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        unselectedColor: Colors.greenAccent[200],
                        buttonIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        ),

                        searchHintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        searchable: true,
                        buttonText: Text(
                          '$Preligion', //"",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 5,
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          "Religions",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            color: Colors.pink,
                          ),
                        ),
                        items: _items,
                        onConfirm: (values) {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedItems2 = values;
                          });
                          print('selected : ${_selectedItems2}');

                          senduserdata('partnerreligion', '${_selectedItems2.toString()}');
                        },
                        chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          onTap: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedItems2.remove(value);
                            });

                            print('removed: ${_selectedItems2.toString()}');
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      _selectedItems2 == null || _selectedItems2.isEmpty
                          ? MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                              onTap: (item) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedItems3.remove(item);
                                  print(
                                      'removed below: ${_selectedItems3.toString()}');
                                });
                                _multiSelectKey.currentState.validate();
                              },
                            )
                          : MultiSelectChipDisplay(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

can anyone guide me if I am making any mistake here?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Because `onConfirm` return `List<Religions>`

```
/// Fires when confirm is tapped.
  final void Function(List<V>) onConfirm;
```

Step 1: Use `MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Religions>`

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Religions>(
```

Step 2: `_selectedItems2` use `forEach`

```
    _selectedItems2.forEach((item) {
                    print("${item.id} ${item.name}");
                    Preligion = "$Preligion ${item.name}";
                  });
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/bottom_sheet/multi_select_bottom_sheet_field.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/chip_display/multi_select_chip_display.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/util/multi_select_item.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/util/multi_select_list_type.dart';

class Religions {
  int id;
  String name;

  Religions({this.id, this.name});
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static List<Religions> _religion = [
    Religions(id: 1, name: "Agnostic"),
    Religions(id: 2, name: "Atheist"),
    Religions(id: 3, name: "Buddhist"),
    Religions(id: 4, name: "Christian"),
    Religions(id: 5, name: "Hindu"),
    Religions(id: 6, name: "Jain"),
    Religions(id: 7, name: "Jewish"),
    Religions(id: 8, name: "Muslim"),
    Religions(id: 9, name: "Zoroastrian"),
    Religions(id: 10, name: "Sikh"),
    Religions(id: 11, name: "Spiritual"),
    Religions(id: 12, name: "Other"),
  ];
  final _items = _religion
      .map((item) => MultiSelectItem<Religions>(item, item.name))
      .toList();
  List<Religions> _selectedItems2 = [];
  List<Religions> _selectedItems3 = [];
  final _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  String Preligion = "test";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Religions>(
              initialChildSize: 0.7,
              maxChildSize: 0.95,
              listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
              checkColor: Colors.pink,
              selectedColor: Colors.pink,
              selectedItemsTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              unselectedColor: Colors.greenAccent[200],
              buttonIcon: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              ),
              searchHintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
              searchable: true,
              buttonText: Text(
                '$Preligion', //"????",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 5,
              ),
              title: Text(
                "Religions",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ),
              items: _items,
              onConfirm: (values) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedItems2 = values;
                });
                print('selected : ${_selectedItems2}');

                _selectedItems2
                    .forEach((item) => print("${item.id} ${item.name}"));
                /*senduserdata(
                    'partnerreligion', '${_selectedItems2.toString()}');*/
              },
              chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onTap: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedItems2.remove(value);
                  });

                  print('removed: ${_selectedItems2.toString()}');
                },
              ),
            ),
            _selectedItems2 == null || _selectedItems2.isEmpty
                ? MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                    onTap: (item) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedItems3.remove(item);
                        print('removed below: ${_selectedItems3.toString()}');
                      });
                      _multiSelectKey.currentState.validate();
                    },
                  )
                : MultiSelectChipDisplay(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```